# Service is not returning the data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service with a method like below:

```
getTotalCountries() {
    this.http.get("country").subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response.json());//it is displaying all the data which is return by API
      return response.json();           
    });
}
```

In similar way I have function in component like below:

```
public users: any

countCountry() {
    this.count=this.user.getTotalCountries();
    console.log(this.count) //it is not returning any data;
}
```

I'm not able to figure out why it is not returning data in `component.ts`. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: HTTP client  its will give you Json

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: People - 1) no return 2) async code.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not returning anything because there is no `return` statement.

It should be

```
getTotalCountries(){
    return this.http.get("country");
  }
```

and later on somewhere in the code, when you `subscribe` you will make actual request happen

```
this.user.getTotalCountries().subscribe(val=>this.count=val));
```

You must be aware that here you have to deal with **async** code, so that is something that happens out of order.

When you `subscribe` application continues and actual http call is made in the background. When request finishes, callback is invoked - and that is the code you provide as argument to `subscribe`.

Comment: I tried your way but still not getting data in `component.ts`

Comment: `val.json()` maybe? If still no luck, create stackblitz.

Comment: yeah it is working fine. I want to know to one thing could you please tell me

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
return this.http.get('country').subscribe { .......}
```